# Finding equation of the plane

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the plane.
The plane through the point 
$(7,0,-3)$ and
  contains the line 
x = 4 − 3t, y = 2 + 5t, z = 6 + 4t

I've gotten 53x-15y but i don't know what the z component would be and I keep messing up what that would equal to

Comment: I've gotten 53x-15y but i don't know what the z component would be and I keep messing up what that would equal too

Answer (score 1):

For $t =0$ and $t=1$ the points $A=(4,2,6)$ and $B=(1,7,10)$ belongs to the plane respectively.

Let $u$ be the vector from $A=(4,2,6)$ to $B=(1,7,10)\rightarrow u=(-3,5,4)$

Let $v$ be the vector from $A=(4,2,6)$ to $C=(7,0,-3)\rightarrow v=(3,-2,-9)$

The normal vector to these vectors can be found by the following 
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
i & j & k\\
-3 & 5 & 4\\
3 & -2 & -9
\end{array}\right| & =-37i-15j-9k
\end{align*}
$$

The equation of the plane through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is 
$$n.<x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0>$$
where $n$ is the normal vector of the plane and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(7,0,-3)$

So
$$<-37,-15,-9>.<x-7,y-0,z-(-3)>=-37(x-7)-15y-9(z+3)$$